# Uploading single File mongoDb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

When I'm making multiple upload it's working fine, but when I'm uploading single file it doesn't work. it says **TypeError: req.body.file.map is not a function**

I don't know what's happening here. is it because I map already the req.body?

```
    exports.create = (req, res) => {
    const { name, description, price, category, quantity, url } = req.body
    if (!name || !description || !price || !category || !quantity ) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: "All fields must be filled"
        })
    }

    req.body.images = req.body.file.map(function (obj) {
      const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
      return {
        url: obj,
        id: id,
        isApproved: false,
      };
    });

    req.body.shop = req.params.shopId;
    let product = new Product(req.body);

    var product_images = req.files;
    var arrayofId = product_images.map(function (obj) {
        return obj.id;
    })


    product.save((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: `Error on saving product: ${dbErrorHandler(err)}`
            });
        }
        connection.db.collection("productimage.files", function(err, collection){
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: `Error on saving image: ${dbErrorHandler(err)}`
                });
            }   
            collection.updateMany({
                _id:
                    {
                        $in: arrayofId
                    }
            }, {
                $set: { aliases: [result._id.toString()] }
            });
        });
        res.json(result);
    });
    
};
```

This is my uploadProduct

```
    export const addProduct = async (productData, shopId, url) => {
    const ls = new SecureLS({ encodingType: "aes" });

    const token = ls.get("token");

    const formdata = new FormData();


    for (let index = 0; index < productData.images.length; index++) {
        formdata.append("file", productData.images[index]);
    }

    formdata.append("category", productData.category);
    formdata.append("name", productData.name);
    formdata.append("quantity", productData.quantity);
    formdata.append("price", productData.price);
    formdata.append("description", productData.description);
    formdata.append("ingredients", productData.ingredients);
    formdata.append("url", url);

    return await fetch(`${API}/product/${shopId}`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
        body: formdata,
    })
        .then((response) => {
            return response;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            //console.log(err)
            return err;
        });
};
```

I'm wanting to also be able to upload a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you upload single file, `req.body.file` is not an **array**.

In your upload function:

```js
for (let index = 0; index < productData.images.length; index++) {
     formdata.append("file", productData.images[index]);
}
```

you should change to

```js
for (let index = 0; index < productData.images.length; index++) {
     formdata.append("file[]", productData.images[index]);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: is it okay if I just change it in frontend and not in the backend?

Answer (score 1):

when you upload multiple files it becomes an array and your map function works perfectly.
but when you upload a single file it's not an array and you get the array.
the map is an array function.

for example:

```js
let req = {body: {
    file: []
    
}};
req.body.file.map(x=>something);
```

the above function will work perfectly but if you do like this

```js
let req = {body: {
    file: "value"
    
}};
req.body.file.map(x=>something);
```

this will through error "req.body.file.map is not a function"

**Solution**
send files data in the array from the client-side even if a single file
or
check file if is an array the apply the map otherwise treat this single file

Comment: I tried req it says req has already been declared.

Comment: just send array of files from the frontend even if its a single file, backend code is good enough.